# http request await sync in repetitive function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

I have a problem with a repetitive function with an HTTP request.

When I call the getDocument() function, a result appears at the end of the console but unfortunately not in the frontend. I get a new json array by the call where also the render() function should be applied.

I render the ouput after each run of the render() function in the HTML view.

It seems to me that the HTTP.request is too slow and can't keep up with the repeating function. I have read up a bit on async await but am still having problems using it correctly.

```
var jsonArray = [
    {
        etype: 'normal',
        content: 'renderContent'
    },
    {
        etype: 'extern',
        id: 'MyIdToDocument',
        subcontent: [
           { 
            etype: 'normal',
            content: 'renderContent'
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        etype: 'normal',
        content: 'renderContent'
    }
]

jsonArray.forEach(object => {
    this.render(object)
});


function render(object) {

    if(object.etype ==='normal') {
        object.subcontent.forEach( subcontentItem => {
           output = this.render(subcontentItem)        
        })
    }

    if(object.etype ==='extern') {
        output = this.getDocument(object.id)
    }

    return output;
}

function getDocument(id) {
    this.httpClient.post('myAPiUrl/', id).subscribe(response => {
        response.forEach(object => {
            this.render(object)
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: You are doing a recursive function call, probably that is why something is missing based on API response

Comment: the code above is not complete and is missing a few things, but in general you are messing with the order by calling subscribe in the forEach loop. You should never do that, because you don't know when the value via the Observable will be delivered. 

You can read more about async await approach with Promises or join Observable streams of data using rxjs operators.

Comment: The subscribe function in getDocument won't execute until the POST request has finished.  That won't start to happen until any javascript executing on your page is complete.  Please don't assume that `this.render` is going to wait for HTTP calls created by `this.getDocument` to complete, unless you explicitly tell it to, via async/await or similar.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now i know the Problem but what would be a proper way to code this correct?